# Subquery with WHERE IN and MIN

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I do have an array like:

```
$inQuery = (1, 2, 3,...)
```

I want to get from the table portfolio the articles with the minium price value. My Query:

```
SELECT  *
        FROM portfolio p
        WHERE p.article_id IN ($inQuery) = (
           SELECT MIN(p.net_price)
           FROM portfolio p);
        AND p.state_id = (:state_id)
```

How can I get the entry form portfolio with different articles and minium price?

Answer (score 1):

If you have index on net_price (I assume you have because no indexing on the col then the Select MIN(p.net_price) will scan whole table, thats not good), then i think you should do 2 queries which might better using index:

```
1. $minPrice= Select MIN(net_price) from portfolio;

2. SELECT  *
    FROM portfolio p
    WHERE p.article_id IN ($inQuery) AND net_price = $minPrice
    AND p.state_id = (:state_id)
```

If you have covering index on (net_price,state_id, article_id), would be great